# Mat paginator change tooltip position

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to position tooltip of `mat-paginator` closer to the pagination buttons. Currently, tooltip is too far away, see below:

[image]

I tried to update `.cdk-overlay-pane` and `.mat-tooltip-panel` classes but didn't work for me. Any points are highly appreciated!

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @HarshNagalla Sadly, no

Comment: Actually this quite a weird issue, I don't understand how does it go out of place and i am also not able to disable it.

Comment: Are you able to disable it?

Comment: @HarshNagalla You can use this on init `this.paginator._intl.nextPageLabel = '';` to hide the tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Need to go deep inside component

```
::ng-deep body .cdk-overlay-container {
    .mat-tooltip {
        top: 104px;
    }
}
```

Comment: This targets all mat-tooltips on the page so it's not a valid solution

Answer (score 0):

apply bottom style to mat-tooltip-panel class. It can resolve the issue..and it worked for me

```
::ng-deep body .cdk-overlay-container {
  .mat-tooltip-panel {
    bottom: 100px !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom MatPaginatorIntl and set the labels to empty strings:

```
import { MatPaginatorIntl } from '@angular/material';

export class MatPaginatorHideLabels extends MatPaginatorIntl {
   itemsPerPageLabel = '';
   nextPageLabel     = '';
   previousPageLabel = '';
}
```

And then you can either add it to your global providers or you can add it to the providers on your component if you want to be more specific.

```
@Component({
    providers: [{ provide: MatPaginatorIntl, useClass: MatPaginatorHideLabels }]
})
```