# how to change mat-paginator tooltip position?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

set tooltip below the next button

[image: i can try to tooltip show below the next button but show above button]

I am also try this

html

```
<mat-paginator
    [ngClass]="{ 'mat-paginator-actions': !showpageof }"
    #paginator
    [length]="totalpageSizes"
    [hidePageSize]="true"
    [pageIndex]="pageindex"
    [pageSize]="pagesize"
    (page)="pagechange($event)"
  >
  </mat-paginator>
```

scss

```
 .mat-tooltip {
        top: 104px;
    }
```

but this css are affected for all tooltip. how to perticular mat-paginator tooltip below the button.

Comment: Did you tried setting tool-tip position to below like mention here https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples

Comment: @Awais Thanks. But tooltip not define by me. default tooltip show in mat-paginator.

Comment: Oh! Then i would suggest you to set it display none and try to use some custom tool-tip like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58316885/angular-material-tool-tip-with-html-support

Comment: yes, but  how I can add custom tooltip in next and previous button .

Comment: May be this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52473252/mat-paginator-change-tooltip-position

Comment: already I tried. but no result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208630/discussion-between-vijay-prajapati-and-awais).